# Understanding DefaultIfEmpty in LINQ

Tags: c#, defaultifempty

I don't understand how `DefaultIfEmpty` method works. It is usually used to be reminiscent of left-outer join in LINQ.

- `DefaultIfEmpty()` method must be run on a *collection*.
- `DefaultIfEmpty()` method cannot be run on `null` collection reference.

A code example I don't understand some points that

- Does `p`, which is after `into` keyword, refer to `products`?
- Is `ps` the group of product objects? I mean a sequence of sequences.
- If `DefaultIfEmpty()` isn't used, doesn't **p**, `from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()`, run into `select`? Why?

,

```
#region left-outer-join
string[] categories = {
    "Beverages",
    "Condiments",
    "Vegetables",
    "Dairy Products",
    "Seafood"
};

List<Product> products = GetProductList();

var q = from c in categories
        join p in products on c equals p.Category into ps
        from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select (Category: c, ProductName: p == null ? "(No products)" : p.ProductName);

foreach (var v in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{v.ProductName}: {v.Category}");
}
#endregion
```

Code from [101 Examples of LINQ](https://github.com/dotnet/try-samples/blob/master/101-linq-samples/src/JoinOperations.cs#L92).

Comment: You are calling DefaultIfEmpty on the list of lists, which is never empty. Your supplied default value is never used. Call it on elem instead. Check the MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty

Comment: i think you should use ``elem.DefaultIfEmpty`` inside loop.

Comment: @Sajid is there any point you don't get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ain't generally answer my own question, however, I think some people might find the question somewhat intricate.
In the first step, the working logic of the `DefaultIfEmpty` method group should be figured out(LINQ doesn't support its overloaded versions, by the by).

```
class foo
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
// list1
var l1 = new List<foo>();
//l1.Add(null);     --> try the code too by uncommenting
//list2
var l2 = l1.DefaultIfEmpty();

foreach (var x in l1)
    Console.WriteLine((x == null ? "null" : "not null") + "  entered l1");

foreach (var x in l2)
    Console.WriteLine((x == null ? "null" : "not null") + "  entered l2");
```

When being run, seeing that it gives `null  entered l2 out` result out.
What if `l1.Add(null);` is commented in? It is at your disposal, not hard to guess at all.

`l2` has an *item* which is of `null` since `foo` is not one of the building block types like `Int32`, `String`, or `Char`. If it were, default promotion would be applied to, e.g. for string, `" "`(blank character) is supplied to.

Now let's examine the LINQ statement being mentioned.

> Just for a remembrance, unless an aggregate operator or a To{a
>   collection}() is applied to a LINQ expression, lazy evaluation(honor
>   deferred) is carried out.

[image]

The followed image, albeit not belonging to C#, helps to get what it means.

In the light of the lazy evaluation, we are now wisely cognizant of the fact that the LINQ using *query expression* is evaluated when requested, that is, on-demand.

[image]

So, `ps` contains product items iff the equality expressed at `on` keyword of `join` is satisfied. Further, `ps` has different product items at each demand of the LINQ expression. Otherwise, unless `DefaultIfEmpty()` is used, `select` is not hit thereby not iterating over and not yielding any `Console.WriteLine($"{productName}: {category}");`. (Please correct me at this point if I'm wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

### Answers

> ```
> Does p refer to products after into keyword?
> ```

The p in the `from` clause is a new local variable referring to a single product of one category.

> ```
> Is ps the group of product objects? I mean a sequence of sequences.
> ```

Yes, `ps` is the group of products for the category `c`. But it is not a sequence of sequences, just a simple `IEnumerable<Product>`, just like `c` is a single category, not all categories in the group join.

In the query you only see data for one result *row*, never the whole group join result. Look at the final `select`, it prints *one* category and *one* product it joined with. That product comes from the `ps` group of product that *one* category joined with.

The query then does the walking over all categories and all their groups of products.

> ```
> If DefaultIfEmpty() isn't used, doesn't p, from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty(), run into select? Why?
> ```

It is not equal to a `Select`, because the `from` clause creates a new join with itself, which turns into `SelectMany`.

### Structure

Taking the query by parts, first the group join:

```
from c in categories
join p in products on c equals p.Category into ps
```

After this only `c` and `ps` are usable, representing a category and its joined products.

Now note that the **whole** query is in the same form as:

```
from car in Cars
from passenger in car.Passengers
select (car, passenger)
```

Which joins `Cars` with its own `Passengers` using `Cars.SelectMany(car => car.Passengers, (car, passenger) => (car, passenger));`

So in your query

```
from group_join_result into ps
from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

creates a new join of the previous group join result with its own data (lists of grouped products) ran through DefaultIfEmpty using SelectMany.

### Conclusion

In the end the complexity is in the Linq query and not the DefaultIfEmpty method. The method is simply explained on the MSDN page i posted in comment. It simply turns a collection with no elements into collection that has 1 element, which is either the default() value or the supplied value.

### Compiled source

This is approximately the C# code the query gets compiled to:

```
        //Pairs of: (category, the products that joined with the category)
        IEnumerable<(string category, IEnumerable<Product> groupedProducts)> groupJoinData = Enumerable.GroupJoin(
            categories,
            products,
            (string c) => c,
            (Product p) => p.Category,
            (string c, IEnumerable<Product> ps) => (c, ps)
        );

        //Flattening of the pair collection, calling DefaultIfEmpty on each joined group of products
        IEnumerable<(string Category, string ProductName)> q = groupJoinData.SelectMany(
                    catProdsPair => catProdsPair.groupedProducts.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    (catProdsPair, p) => (catProdsPair.category, (p == null) ? "(No products)" : p.ProductName)
        );
```

Done with the help of ILSpy using C# 8.0 view.

Comment: It simply turns a collection with no elements into the collection that has 1 element --> in my example, there is already data its inside, no need to use DefaultIfEmpty()? I mean ps has data already.

Comment: @snr Not necessarily. ps is the group of product for one category. If a category did not join with any products then that group will be empty. So ps is *not* the result of group join, just a single group of products belonging to a single category c.